# View vs LazyList

Tags: scala, thread-safety, scala-collections

```scala
val patterns = Seq(
  "the name and age are ([a-z]+), ([0-9]+)".r,
  "name:([a-z]+),age:([0-9]+)".r,
  "n=([a-z]+),a=([0-9]+)".r
)
def transform(subject: String): Option[String] = {
  patterns.map(_.unapplySeq(subject)).collectFirst { case Some(List(name, age)) => s"$name$age" }
}
println(transform("name:joe,age:42")) // Some(joe42)
```

This code that finds and transforms the first match in a list of regexes can be improved by returning early for the average case

What is the best way to make `patterns` a lazy collection taking into consideration **performance** and **thread safety**? Can a view be reused by multiple threads or should a new view be created for each invocation of `transform`?

1. `patterns.view`
2. `patterns.to(LazyList)`

Comment: Why not use a single regex pattern? Then the laziness is built-in.

Comment: That's true but it becomes harder to extract the match: `Some(List(joe, 42))` vs `Some(List(name:joe,age:42, null, null, joe, 42, null, null))`. Especially when more patterns are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still feel that there could be advantages when using a single regex pattern.

```
val pattern = List("the name and age are (\\w+), (\\d+)"
                  ,"name:(\\w+),age:(\\d+)"
                  // add more as needed
                  ,"n=(\\w+),a=(\\d+)"
                  ).mkString("|").r

def transform(subject: String): Option[String] =
  pattern.findFirstMatchIn(subject)
         .map(_.subgroups.filter(_ != null).mkString)
```

Comment: What if there are 1000 patterns? Even if the first pattern matches (best case), `.filter` has to iterate over all the patterns

Comment: True enough, but 1000 separately compiled patterns or 1000 patterns combined into a single compilation, either way it's asking a lot from regex. A proper parser-combinator might be a better tool for such a task.